# What is the max lenght of a input text in php post request?

Tags: php, html, apache, symfony

What is the max lenght of a input text in php post request ?

I need to post in a form symfony  a very large json object in one input text but when the input is too large the data is from the input in the symfony controler is null.

I found some answers : set max_input_vars, max_upload_file in php.ini for change the apache configuration but it's does not work.

For example i have a input with value length = 4837112

So i'm asking if anyone know how disable the limit of the input text or set a biggest value to the limit ? 
And if it's php or apache or maybe symfony which poses this problems ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment yet because I don't have the rep to do so but I'll explain a few things. Also, please post some of your code, it would be very helpful.

When you POST something through PHP, the limit can be set in php.ini (or equivalent) and the httpd service must be restarted to take effect. If it's still not taking effect, then you have to take a few things into consideration.

1. Am I editing the correct values?
2. Do I have a non-standard installation like two versions of apache installed?
3. Do I have an override set somewhere else like htaccess or a setting in your framework?
4. Is the data REALLY sending?

You'll need to have something like firebug to help you debug this (click on console). If you see the data POST, have it return to you for debug purposes. If it doesn't come back but it does post, it could be one of the above or there's something wrong in your code.

Comment: Thank you , you help me , in fact the data has not really .. sends the input value is not limited , but the chrome or other browsers set a limit to 524288 . it was my problem. (I have not the rep like you to set your answer is usefull sorry )